# Why is Postman Collection Runner unable to detect data file type?

Tags: json, postman, postman-collection-runner

I use Postman Collection Runner with json data files - a lot of them and only json, no csv. Whenever I load or change the data file, the "Data File Type" dropdown switches to "Undetermined" and I have to switch it back to application/json all the time. Really annoying.
Ist there a way to let the Collection Runner know that this is a json file or at least stop it to switch back to undetermined all the time?

Comment: Is this on a Windows or Linux machine? - There was an issue that was opened and closed 5 months ago. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4353

Comment: It's Postman 6.2.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: Same for me - The demo video on the closed ticket was done on a Mac so maybe they thought it wasn't a problem and closed the ticket without actually looking deeper into the problem.